# Materials or sample code for column generation book (GERAD 25th Anniversary Series)

Tags: solver, combinatorial-optimization, column-generation

As far as I know, one of the interesting resources to learn the basic concept of the decomposition methods is ***column generation book (GERAD 25th Anniversary Series)***, which has been mentioned in some useful community Q&A like [this](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/291/reference-for-column-generation-applications), but unlikely there are no more materials/sample codes to reproduce whose examples (maybe, I cannot find that).

I would like to know, are there any sample codes, specifically, based on the Java or Python API of CPLEX/Gurobi/SCIP, to benchmark them?

Comment: Perhaps, a request must be made to the authors.

Comment: @MatheusDiógenesAndrade, thanks. I, actually, did that, but the author said it is somewhat old, is also written in a different language, and the source code is not now available. This is why I asked this question and hopefully, someone may have some similarity.

Comment: @Omidi I see. That is unfortunate.